# How do i load the package self in perl?

Tags: perl

Right now I'm trying to generate XML and print it out from Perl. I found this module, XML::Write, which looked rather nice. But when i wanted to try it out i ran in to some rather strange errors...

My test script looks like this

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use strict 'refs';
use XML::Writer;

my $writer = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => 'self');
$writer->xmlDecl("ISO-8859-1");
$writer->startTag("foo");
$writer->endTag("foo");
$writer->end;
print $writer->to_string;
```

and when I run it the only output is

Can't locate object method "print" via package "self" (perhaps you forgot to load "self"?) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/XML/Writer.pm line 132.

What am I missing? Do i have to install some extra module to make the OO parts of perl avaliable? Should I somehow install an old version of XML::Write since I have a rather old Perl version?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What version are you running? (`perl -MXML::Writer -e'print "$XML::Writer::VERSION\n"'`)

Comment: How are you executing the program ?

Comment: Well when i try to execute it, it works fine. Maybe you need to reinstall the module

Comment: Works here too (perl 5.14.2, XML-Writer 0.623 on ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Im running Perl verion 5.8.8 and perl -MXML::Writer -e'print "$XML::Writer::VERSION\n"' returns 0.612

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The special value `self` for the `OUTPUT` option of the constructor was added in [v0.620](https://metacpan.org/module/JOSEPHW/XML-Writer-0.620/Writer.pm). Previously, it expected an `IO::Handle` or a scalar reference.

Install the current version to be able to use this feature, or consult the documentation of [the version you have installed](https://metacpan.org/module/JOSEPHW/XML-Writer-0.612/Writer.pm) (e.g. with command-line `perldoc XML::Writer` or by selecting your version in the “Go to version” drop-down list on the [metacpan page](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aWriter).)

For your use case, you can supply a reference:

```
my $output;
my $writer = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => \$output);
...;
print $output;
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it (sort of...). When using use strict 'refs' it complains about the print statement but if I change it to my $output = ''; and print $output everything works just fine.

Comment: `print $output` should be all you need to make to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message. My problem was that I was missing a `$`sign in the body of the module I was trying to load. There was an instruction `self->...` that should have been `$self->....`

I hope this helps